# Optimizing an avatar toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link (avatar)`#qam-account-toggle` and `div.qam-account-items`, the div containing user account links. I am toggling div on avatar click as well as click anywhere but `div.qam-account-items`

Here is my code. How can I optimize this better?

```
$('#qam-account-toggle').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass('account-active');
    $('.qam-account-items').fadeToggle('fast');
});

$(document).click(function(){
    $('#qam-account-toggle.account-active').removeClass('account-active');
    $('.qam-account-items:visible').hide();
});

$('.qam-account-items').click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest wrapping the code in a function, so it's all in one place and can share variables. Then there's no need to find and re-find the same elements in each event handler.

Also, you're doing some extra filtering by class name and such which is unnecessary. E.g. `.hide()` will hide whatever's visible, so you don't need to first use `:visible` to find the visible elements.

```
function enableAccountItemsToggling() {
  // find these once
  var accountToggle = $('#qam-account-toggle'),
      accountItems  = $('.qam-account-items');

  // toggle items
  accountToggle.on("click", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    accountToggle.toggleClass('account-active');
    accountItems.fadeToggle('fast');

    // a single click is enough; no need for a persistent event handler
    // so we use .one() instead of .on()
    $(document).one("click", function () {
      accountToggle.removeClass("account-active");
      accountItems.fadeOut("fast");
    });
  });

  accountItems.on("click", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not much to say here, it looks pretty good. I've moved to only using `.on` for attaching events as I think it encourages better practices. Remember it's better to save selectors as variables if you are going to reuse them.

Instead of catching the click on `.qam-account-items` you can just fire the event on everything but those classes;

```
$(document).on('click', '*:not(.qam-account-items)', function() {
    $('#qam-account-toggle.account-active').removeClass('account-active');
    $('.qam-account-items:visible').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this code is not working. stopped show hide.. any idea why is that?

Comment: I see this code is only for ignoring `qam-account-items` but it is still hiding it when I click on input box within the div

Comment: @pixelngrain Yeah you're right... I'll mull it over.

Comment: Any idea how to fix it?